# Conditional expression for RegExp issue

Tags: javascript, regex

Having fun with Regex and I'm wondering if there is a way to setup a conditional in regexp  based on certain critera - looking to return whats between A or B and B or A - but it doesn't seem to be working in my regex 101 given the following string:

```
 (?<=A|B\s+).*?(?=\s+B|A) //<-hopefully should return anything between or an A or a B is this possible?

    A
adawdawdawwad
B

awdawdawdda
A
awdaddawdaw

B
awdadadaw
B
awdadadaw
A
adadawaw

B
awdawdwadawd
A
```

Comment: you are missing brackets I believe (?<=(A|B)\s+).*?(?=\s+(B|A))

Answer (score 2):

In the current pattern `(?<=A|B\s+).*?(?=\s+B|A)`, the beginning asserts what is on the left is either A or a B when the B is followed by 1 or more whitespace characters. The same applies for the end of the pattern but then using a positive lookahead.

You could put the A and B in a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
(?<=[AB]\s+).*?(?=\s+[AB])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a7P5x6/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=[AB]\s+).*?(?=\s+[AB])/g;
const str = `    A
adawdawdawwad
B

awdawdawdda
A
awdaddawdaw

B
awdadadaw
B
awdadadaw
A
adadawaw

B
awdawdwadawd
A`;

console.log(str.match(regex));
```

---

As the lookbehind `(?<=` is not yet widely supported in all browsers, you could also make use of a match and a capturing group.

Use only the positive lookahead asserting what is on the right is 1+ whitespace chars and either A or B:

```
[AB]\s+(.*?)(?=\s+[AB])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MVjDvp/1)

```js
const regex = /[AB]\s+(.*?)(?=\s+[AB])/g;
const str = `    A
adawdawdawwad
B

awdawdawdda
A
awdaddawdaw

B
awdadadaw
B
awdadadaw
A
adadawaw

B
awdawdwadawd
A`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular expression

```
(?<=^ *A *\r?\n)(?:(?!^ *B *?$).*\r?\n)*(?=^ *B *?$)|(?<=^ *B *\r?\n)(?:(?!^ *A\s*$).*\r?\n)*(?=^ *A *?$)
```

[Javascript demo](https://regex101.com/r/uATY7C/2/)

This will match all the text between a line containing only `A` and zero or more spaces and the next line that contains only `B` and zero or more spaces, and all the text between a line containing only `B` and zero or more spaces and the next line that contains only `A` and zero or more spaces.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<=            # begin positive lookbehind
  ^ *A\ *\r?\n  # match 0+ spaces, 'A', 0+ spaces, opt CR,
                # newline, from beginning of line
)               # end positive lookbehind
(?:             # begin non-capture group
  (?!           # begin negative lookahead
    ^ *B *$     # match 0+ spaces, 'B', 0+ spaces, end of
                # line, from beginning of line  
  )             # end negative lookahead
  .*\r?\n       # match 0+ chars, opt CR, newline
)               # end non-capture group
*               # execute non-capture group 0+ times
(?=             # begin positive lookahead
  ^ *B *?$      # match 0+ spaces, 'B', 0+ spaces, end of
                # line, from beginning of line  
)               # end positive lookahead
|               # or
(?<=            # begin positive lookbehind
  ^ *B\ *\r?\n  # match 0+ spaces, 'B', 0+ spaces, opt CR,
                # newline, from beginning of line
)               # end positive lookbehind
(?:             # begin non-capture group
  (?!           # begin negative lookahead
    ^ *A *$     # match 0+ spaces, 'A', 0+ spaces, end of
                # line, from beginning of line  
  )             # end negative lookahead
  .*\r?\n       # match 0+ chars, opt CR, newline
)               # end non-capture group
*               # execute non-capture group 0+ times
(?=             # begin positive lookahead
  ^ *A *?$      # match 0+ spaces, 'A', 0+ spaces, end of
                # line, from beginning of line  
)               # end positive lookahead
```

Comment: @Lucas, if you mean that the string "`My dog has fleas"` is not extracted from `"AMy dog has fleasB"`, I would agree. I gave my understanding of the question in my sentence that follows the link to the "Javascript demo", which excludes strings such as `"AMy dog has fleasB"`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest one

```
A[^B]+B|B[^A]+A
```